# How to apply a smooth fade in delay effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone can provide a solution to this issue I am having, sorry I'm only a beginner at CSS. 
Basically, I have a landing page where a youtube video plays in the background and I have some buttons that appear after 8 seconds. These buttons I want them to appear smoothly by fading in. I can't work out how to do this and the current css snippet I have is

```
.cover .btn-lg {
  animation: cssAnimation 0s 8s forwards;
 visibility: hidden;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { visibility: visible; }
}
```

Where and what can I change to get the effect I want, so rather than it just appear - I want it to fade in smoothly.

Comment: Did you mean to mark this jquery?  In which case `$(".btn").fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.cover .btn-lg {
  animation: cssAnimation 13s linear;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
   <button class="btn-lg">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @evgeni thanks for that, the keyframes and animation work but I don't want them to start until after 5 seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: @bluewavestudio if you want to wait for 5 seconds exactly then it's better to use javascript this code "wait" for 4.94 second

Answer (score 2):

[Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

[Opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

These two together will allow for the fade effect you desire. It will be hidden by default, add the class .show to your element to start the transition.

```
.cover .btn-lg {
  transition: opacity 8s;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cover .btn-lg .show {
  transition: opacity 8s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, if I replace my snippet with yours.. the buttons no longer appear, sorry

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, I am still new to posting around here, just getting the hang of things!

Comment: @bluewavestudio That is because you must add the .show class to the same element as your .btn-lg class when you want the buttons to appears.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinEllis I've replaced my snippet with yours exactly, something i've missed?